# TSQL in a 3 column table, I need the MAX score with the earliest

Tags: t-sql

I have a 3 column table that shows a person's score and the ID representing the record of their "test attempt".

```
TABLE1
empid   score   attempt_id
1       10565   10001
1       10700   10010
1       12500   10009
1       13000   10025
1       13000   10021
2       10565   10041
2       10700   10020
2       12500   10029
3       13000   10035
4       13000   10051
```

I'm trying to pull a recordset that contains the employee id along with their maximum score and smallest attempt_id (if there are multiple records with the same max score).

```
Result
empid   score   attempt_id
1       13000   10021
2       12500   10029
3       13000   10035
4       13000   10051
```

I can't seem to get the right SQL.

Any help?

Comment: What version of mssql are you using?

Comment: 2008 R2 is the version we're using

Comment: Your question isn't clear.  You're asking for the maximum score and the lowest attempt_id.  For empid=1 that would be 13000 and 10001.  Did you mean you want to highest score and the attempt_id associated with it?

Comment: Yes - the highest score and it's associated attempt_id.  In this case, there could be multiple records with the same maximum score; in which case I need the smallest attempt_id of those records

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a whirl..  Get the max score and put it in a subquery, then in the main query join to it and get the min attempt.

`SELECT ms.empid, ms.max_score, MIN(attempt_id) 
FROM Table1 ma
JOIN (
   SELECT empid, Max(score) as max_score
   FROM Table1
   GROUP BY empid ) ms ON ma.empid = ms.empid AND ma.score = ms.max_score
GROUP BY ms.empid, ms.max_score
ORDER BY ms.empid`

Comment: It worked - but I needed to add GROUP BY ms.empid, ms.max_score